# Input and Output date class Java

Tags: java, arrays, date

I'm doing a class date project where user input the date and output the date into 3 difference formats. 
a) MM/DD/YYYY
b) MonthName DD, YYYY
c) DDD, YYYY (date of the year).

I got stuck at one point, where output the result for part a. Here what I got so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Implementation
{
    private static int month;
    private static int day;
    private static int year;
    private static final int[] daysPerMonth = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
    public static void Date(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(year != -1)
        {    
        System.out.print("Enter month: ");
        month = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter day: ");
        day = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter year: ");
        year = input.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("\nMM/DD/YYYY: %d/%d/%d");
        System.out.printf("\nMonth DD/YYYY: ");
        System.out.println("\nDDD YYYY: \n");
        }    
    }    
    public Implementation(int month, int day, int year)
        {
        if (month <= 0 || month > 12)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "month (" + month + ") must be 1-12");
        if (day <= 0 | (day > daysPerMonth[month] && !(month == 2 && day == 29)))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
            ("day (" + day + ") out-of-range for the specified month and year");
        if (month == 2 && day == 29 && !(year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
            ("day (" + day + ") out-of-range for the specified month and year");

        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
        this.year = year;
        }
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%d/%d/%d", month, day, year);
    }
}
```

What should I put right after this `System.out.printf("\nMM/DD/YYYY: %d/%d/%d");` to show up the result (with valid month,day,and year). I haven't done the others two options yet. I'm beginner and very frustrated in this project. Anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are forget using SimpleDateFormat. You are using `String.format`. It's better to avoid while formatting date. You may try this -

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy"); //for (a)
Date dateString = formatter.parse(strDate);
```

Thanks

Comment: What does SimpleDateFormat actually do? Isn't it something with current Date time? I'm new, can you explain it more clearly please?

Comment: From the java doc directly - "SimpleDateFormat is a concrete class for formatting and parsing dates in a locale-sensitive manner. It allows for formatting (date -> text), parsing (text -> date), and normalization" . You may see here for more information - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 21);
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
System.out.println(format.format(c.getTime()));
Output:
21-10-2014
```

Comment: I don't get it much. I think this way is hard coding, which it is not what I really want. Thanks

Comment: You have month, day, year from user, so use those variable instead of 10,21,2014.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to output some text using printf like the following line, you need to tell the method what you actually want it to print.

For this line:

```
System.out.printf("\nMM/DD/YYYY: %d/%d/%d");
```

You need to put in the variables for the month, day and year into the printf method otherwise the method will just print what's inside the double quotes.

So the correct way to do it here is this:

```
System.out.printf("\nMM/DD/YYYY: %d/%d/%d", month, day, year);
```

Java will replace the %d symbols with the values inside the variables after the comma in the arguments and print out the text. The first %d is replaced by the first variable (in this case "month") and the second %d is replaced by the second variable ("day") and so on. (%d is used when the variable is an int, %f is used when it's a float, etc)

[Documentation on Java String formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html)